# Android Studio annoying green background in lines

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android Studio is showing me annoying green lines in XML files. How can I remove it? Thanks.

[image: Annoying green lines]

Comment: Just curious... which platform are you on?

Answer (score 3):

The green lines show areas interpreted by IDE as different language injection.

In those areas you end up with different code completion rules etc.

So assuming you used the language injections by mistake, clicking the lightbulb and choosing "Un-inject Language/Reference" removes those areas.

It's quicker than going through the settings and prevents any inconsistent highlighting and code completion when editing the file later.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found how to disable it.
Preferences -> Editor -> Color & Fonts -> Injected language fragment (uncheck background).

Comment: It should be noted that the highlighting indicates changes since the last commit when using version control.